# Getting a json answer in a controller

Tags: jquery, symfony

I'm working on modifying entities from a webpage (nothing unusual with Symfony :) ). I currently have an entity that is supposed to be modified. I do that edition with [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable), instead of modifying the entity right after an edition, I store the modified elements in a json and when the user confirms his modifications (through a modal dialog confirm action), I send that JSON to my controller.

And that's when things get worse ^^

I checked that I had the json array is containing the right information. But when I intercept the request, in the controller, it doesn't seem to contain what I want. Here's my controller :

```
public function postorganisationAction(){
    $modifFields = array();
    $content = $this->get("request")->getContent();
    $this->get('logger')->info('request123456 ');
    if (!empty($content))
    {
        $modifFields = json_decode($content, true);
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getEntityManager()
               ->getRepository('MyBundle:Organisation');
        $organisation = $repository->findById($modifFields["id"]);
        $organisation->setFromArray($modifFields);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $em->persist($organisation);

        $em->flush();
    }

}
```

The setFromArray function gets an array containing elements such as `"name" => "newname"`.

When I try to log either the request, the content, or `$modifFields["id"]` (as I said, I checked that the id in the JSON is right in the jquery), the log doesn't appear.

Anyone having a clue on what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:

After a few modifications (thanks to ManseUK), I was able to :
- get the jQuery function to send a JSON string and not an array (`JSON.stringify(oModifFields);`)
- troubleshoot the problems : I had a casting error with `$organisation`, which I then turned into an object of the required type

And that's about it ^^

Comment: log the entire content -> `$this->get('logger')->info(var_dump($content));` and see what that returns

Comment: Err... There's nothing in it! Here's the jQuery that sends the request : `oModifFields["id"] = curOId;
                                                    alert(curOId);
                                                    $.post("postorganisation",oModifFields,function(result){
                                                        
                                                    });`

Comment: Your not posting JSON your posting an array ... you need to do the following : `JSON.stringify(oModifFields);` so change `$.post("postorganisation",oModifFields,function(result){ });` to `$.post("postorganisation",JSON.stringify(oModifFields);,function(result){ });`

Comment: I applied the modification, and I'm now sending a JSON, but the `$content` is still empty.

Comment: to get the content try `$content = $this->getRequest()->getContent()`

Comment: Try this -> `var_dump($this->getRequest()->request->all());` at the top of the action - this should dump out the entire content

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12478/discussion-between-manseuk-and-gabriel-theron)

Answer (score 0):

Symfony2 has some useful classes for serializing and deserializing entities.

This is how to proceed:

1. Define a way to normalize an entity into an array, every pair of keys/values of your array will be a key/value in your json string ;
2. Import a serializer, which will transform your array (the entity normalized) into either a json string, XML Document, or whatever you want.

For the first operation (normalize your entity), two possibilities are built-in in Symfony2:

- Implements Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizableInterface on your entity. You will have to fill two methods, which will normalize to or denormalize to an array the properties you want to see in your json;
- Create your own Normalizer Class, which will implement Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface

In the controller (or in a service you will define), you will do the following operation to encode your entities:

```
$serializer = new Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer(
       array(
          new Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\CustomNormalizer(), //if you implement NormalizableInterface
          new YourOwnCustomNormalizer() //if you created your own custom normalizers
       ), 
       array(
          'json' => new Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder()
       )
    );
$json = $serializer->serialize($yourEntity, 'json');
return new Response($json);
```

And to retrieve entities from a json string:

```
$jsonString = $content = $this->get("request")->get('yourString'); //please, check how you retrieve data from your request
$serializer = new Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer(
       array(
          new Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\CustomNormalizer(), //if you implement NormalizableInterface
          new YourOwnCustomNormalizer() //if you created your own custom normalizers
       ), 
       array(
          'json' => new Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder()
       )
    );
$entity = $serializer->deserialize($jsonString, '\namespace\to\your\entity', 'json');
```